# Reading the output of the csv.Sniffer()

Tags: python, csv

I have a file that uses `\x01` as the field delimiter and `\x02\n` for the line terminator. Here is an example of the file header:

```
 #export_date\x01artist_id\x01name\x01is_actual_artist\x01view_url\x01artist_type_id\x02\n
```

When I use `csv.Sniffer()` I get the following:

> {'**module**': 'csv', '_name': 'sniffed', 'lineterminator': '\r\n', 'quoting': 0, '**doc**': None, 'doublequote': False, 'delimiter': '\x01', 'quotechar': '"', 'skipinitialspace': False}

What do the following three fields mean:

- quoting
- quotechar
- doublequote

The above doesn't have any quoting, so I'd assume the `quotechar` should be empty instead of a double quote, but any explanation on these three fields would be great.

Also, I've tried a few other files and it seems to always give the exact output for those three fields, regardless of whether that file has quoting or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation

- *Dialect.doublequote*

> Controls how instances of quotechar appearing inside a field should themselves be quoted. When True, the character is doubled. When False, the escapechar is used as a prefix to the quotechar. It defaults to True.

- *Dialect.quotechar*

> A one-character string used to quote fields containing special characters, such as the delimiter or quotechar, or which contain new-line characters. It defaults to '"'.

- *Dialect.quoting*

> Controls when quotes should be generated by the writer and recognised by the reader. It can take on any of the QUOTE_* constants (see section Module Contents) and defaults to QUOTE_MINIMAL.

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are covered in the [Dialects and Formatting Paramteres docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params):

> - quoting: Controls when quotes should be generated by the writer and recognised by the reader. It can take on any of the QUOTE_* constants (see section Module Contents) and defaults to QUOTE_MINIMAL.
> - doublequote: Controls how instances of quotechar appearing inside a field should themselves be quoted. When True, the character is doubled. When False, the escapechar is used as a prefix to the quotechar. It defaults to True. On output, if doublequote is False and no escapechar is set, Error is raised if a quotechar is found in a field.
> - quotechar: A one-character string used to quote fields containing special characters, such as the delimiter or quotechar, or which contain new-line characters. It defaults to '"'.

Regarding:

> The above doesn't have any quoting, so I'd assume the quotechar should be empty instead of a double quote, but any explanation on these three fields would be great.

There's a comment in the CPython `csv.py` library stating that:

```
# _csv.reader won't accept a quotechar of ''`
```

Source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ef69a1d45de8aa41c45d32d9ee1ff227bb1a566/Lib/csv.py#L198

In your case, if there's no quoting, you probably want to use `csv.QUOTE_NONE`. The sniffer probably couldn't figure that out for you.